# How to manually focus events when fields are auto-populated in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have register user code where if the user selects 'Signup with Google' the fields are auto-populated after the necessary auth process. The problem is that all validations are applied when 'onBlur' event is triggered. But since the fields get auto-populated the onBlur or onFocus does not get fire and hence no validations are done.

Is there a method to manually call them without focusing the input field? The code is too lengthy to share that is why I just need a proper approach to this. The code is in React. TIA

Comment: Hi Alvina ! Since your the fields get auto populated, why not set event based on any of the field value.. Check whether there is some value in the field and call the validation function.. This is one way

Comment: Also, I believe auth0 will have a mechanism to tell what it has come up with... Say an event which is fired on front-end when the data is populated.. Or some  response promise